How to making async calls to Amazon Bedrock
We were trying to make calls in parallel to LLMs hosted in Bedrock, from a lambda layer (in python) only to discover that boto3 does not support async. Is there any workaround? I am looking into aiobotocore / aioboto3, but I do not find any example with Bedrock.
Any hint appreciated and thank you very much!
This is a minimal sample of the code I intended to use, but runs in sequence instead of parallel:
nest_asyncio.apply()

# async summaries
async def _into_comment(segments: list[str]):
    bedrock = boto3.client(
        service_name="bedrock-runtime",
        aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key,
        aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_key,
        aws_session_token=aws_session_token,
        region_name=aws_region
        )
    
    async def sum_up(segment: str):
        body = json.dumps({
            "max_tokens": 256,
            "messages": [{"role": "user", "content": f"Sumarize this: {segment}"}],
            "anthropic_version": "bedrock-2023-05-31"
        })
        return bedrock.invoke_model(body=body, modelId=model_id)
    
    summaries = await asyncio.gather(*[sum_up(segment) for segment in segments])
    return summaries

summaries = asyncio.run(_into_comment(segments))


You can find an example an example with asyncio in the AWS documentation's code example repo.
Link: https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/python/example_code/bedrock-runtime/models/anthropic_claude/converse_async.py
